# Two metrics in one panel grafana - table

Tags: influxdb, grafana

I want to display CPU, Memory Average data in below format for all servers.

```
     Host     CPU_Avg        Mem_Avg
     server1    12.0           23
     server2     13            12
     etc..
```

I have used the below one but display format is not coming as expected.gr[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, select FORMAT AS "Table" instead of "Time series"

Comment: Hi, I changed from Table Series to Table, it showing last value what I have mentioned in query.It doesn't show avg data even though i selected table series aggregations as avg.

Comment: Last and Mean are kind of mutually exclusive: last is supposed to be a single point, mean is several points mapped into a single value. If you know interval when your data is coming try choosing ($__interval) to be equal to that duration. This will allow to get rid of "last" and you will be able to use mean. If this is not what you are looking for, you can play in "Toggle Edit Mode" regime (three horizontal dashes near the eye on the right side of a query)

Comment: SELECT mean(...) FROM ... . In this case "GROUP BY time($interval)" will be necessary, substitute $interval with what's meaningful in your case: 5m, 1h, 1d, etc. It will calculate mean for points that belong to each  interval

Comment: @Anne - Thanks! I got the output as below . I dont want time column instead host column with server name. How to get that one                                                                       `Time        server1:CPU Usage   server1:Disk Usage  server1:Mem Usage                                                                                                                                                                                                      2018-05-21 00:00:00 3.82               78.72         20.26`

Comment: @Madhanika, please, provide your full request as it shown in Grafana (SELECT ...)

Comment: @Anne-`SELECT mean("value") FROM "metrics" WHERE ("host" =~ /^$Server$/ AND "service" = 'CPU Load' OR "host" =~ /^$Server$/ AND "service" = 'Disk usage C:' OR "host" =~ /^$Server$/ AND "service" = 'check_physical_memory') AND $timeFilter GROUP BY "service", "host" ` Format as Time Series